# How to write mongo query for embed document

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I have a requirement where I need to pick different filed from different embeded document

```
{
  "isbn":"1234567890",
  "title":"Mongo db",
  "formats":[
      {"isMaster":"true",
      "digiform":"EBK",
      "isbn":"6563636222"},
      {"isMaster":"false",
      "digiform":"EBGE",
      "isbn":"333554445447"
      },
      {"isMaster":"false",
      "digiform":"HARD",
      "isbn":"776655440011"
      }
   ]
}

{
  "isbn":"11111",
  "title":"SQL",
  "formats":[
      {"isMaster":"false",
      "digiform":"EBK",
      "isbn":"22222"},
      {"isMaster":"false",
      "digiform":"EBGE",
      "isbn":"33333"
      },
      {"isMaster":"false",
      "digiform":"HARD",
      "isbn":"444444"
      }
   ]
}
 {
      "isbn":"AABB11",
      "title":"Linux",
      "formats":[
          {"isMaster":"true",
          "digiform":"EBGE",
          "isbn":"5555555"}
       ]
    }
```

I want to get Title and ISBN of the object for which isMaster true and has atleast one format which has value for digiform as EBGE

so the result would be

```
Title      ISBN   
Mongo db   6563636222 
Linux      5555555
```

Note: I can't modify the object

Comment: Does anything from https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mongo+query+embed+document works for you?

Comment: how will I pick isbn from one of formats objct where isMaster true and digiform is same or other object as EBGE

Comment: You want to fetch all the formats which isMaster is true and what is the another condition can you please explain more clearly ??

Comment: Either with aggregation or $elemMatch. The former allows to re-shape the response, the later is quicker. Please read the similar answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.state.aggregate(

// Pipeline
[
    // Stage 1
    {
        $unwind: {
            path : "$formats",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : false 
        }
    },

    // Stage 2
    {
        $match: {
            "formats.isMaster":"true",
            "formats.digiform":"EBGE"
        }
    },

    // Stage 3
    {
        $group: {
            "_id":"$_id",
            "title":{$last:"$title"},
            "isbn":{$last:"$formats.isbn"}
        }
    },
]);
```